# How to calculate monthly income in bitcoin mining? What is bitcoin difficulty?

Tags: mining-profitability, mining-hardware, raspberry-pi

I'm pretty new to mining. I bought a Raspberry Pi. And I want to know how much bucks I will make when I do mining. The hash rate of Raspberry Pi is 0.4 Mhash/sec (I found on google).
However, when using a Bitcoin calculator I have to put in a value for difficulty. How do I find out the difficulty?

Comment: Please focus on one topic in a question post. If you want to know about multiple topics, create multiple question posts.

Answer (score 0):

Difficulty can be found i.e. by googling "current bitcoin difficulty" - I found this one: http://bitcoindifficulty.com/

As of 2016, the expected income with a rasberry pi is most likely completely  insignificant, not even worth doing the math on it.